# MySQL errors 1064 & 1146

Tags: mysql, sql

While trying to initialise a database in MySQl, we have ran into the same errors (1064 & 1146) numerous times and are out of ideas on how to correct it.
Here is what we have so far:

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (points) REFERENCES GameList (pointsValue)`?? What is this supposed to do?

Comment: One error is a comma after the last line `GROUP BY custCode`.

Comment: @ypercube sorry, it is supposed to take the value from pointsValue and put it into points

Comment: You should always reference columns that have either the `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint. Not only that, here one column is `INT` and the other `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using strings for table names,use back ticks.Also you have foreign keys referencing different column types,they must be the same type and size.Also referenced column must have primary or unique key.

Here it is,but I don't think this is a correct design.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b324)

Comment: We have got the majority of the errors away. Thank you very much and thanks to the other answerers who were also very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just missing commas:

```
CREATE TABLE 'Customer' (
customerCode VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY,
firstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(20)NOT NULL,
pointsTotal VARCHAR(5)
)ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE 'GameList' (
gameCode INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
gameName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
consoleName VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
pointsValue VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

And last select should be like:

```
SELECT custCode,
SUM(points) as pointsTotal from CustomerHistory
GROUP BY custCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last `SELECT` has too many commas, it should be something like

```
SELECT custCode, SUM(points) as pointsTotal 
FROM CustomerHistory
GROUP BY custCode;
```